# Fetch multiple values from excel in selenium webdriver

Tags: excel, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, multiple-columns

I'm new to Selenium and want to repeat an option multiple times.

I have a web application were I should be repeating the same action multiple times and to do this I'm passing values from excel as an input.

I have written a `for loop`, which first gets the row count that is then used until we have completed all the row option

```
for(int i=0;i<row.getLastCellNum();i++) {
    String data12 = sheet2.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
    driver.findElement(By.id("summary")).sendKeys(data12);
    driver.findElement(By.id("clone-issue-submit")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("opsbar-operations_more")).click();
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
    driver.findElement(By.id("clone-issue")).click();
}
```

Now my problem is: I have tested data with two or more rows in excel. For the first execution, the first row is picked and executed, but not for the second row.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you try to isolate your problem? Reading your question, it seems to me the problem is reading your Excel, not running Selenium. Am I right? If so, we would need to see how you're loading the values. If it's in Selenium, is there any exception? Please, check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to try to improve the question with an example.

Comment: Yes, My problem is reading excel using For Loop. i have below code

Comment: i get a error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ForLoop.main(ForLoop.java:25)
for(int i=0;i<=rC;i++)
   {   
   String data1 = sheet2.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
    System.out.println(data1);
when i debug i get error at above line.